# Why do I need to initialize var before redirecting shell with call/wait/output

Tags: rebol

If I try the following code:

```
call/wait/output {webrequest http://google.com login password} content
```

REBOL complains with an error. Instead, I have to use the following:

```
content: ""
call/wait/output {webrequest http://google.com login password} content
```

Why?

Update: I thought answer would be simple ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why?" is a tricky question!  I'll try and give a rationale...

When passing back a value from a function that is supposed to gather data and hand it back, there are two basic options (in most languages).

One is to use it as the `return`.  (In languages like Rebol and Ruby, the implicit return is what the last statement in a code block evaluates to.)  The other way to hand back data is to poke it into a parameter which the caller has passed "by reference" or "by pointer".

Current design of `call` is that it returns the exit code of the process.  But let us imagine an alternate universe where the refinement to `call` of `/output` changed the return value, it might look like this:

```
>> call {echo "test"}
== 0

>> call/output {echo "test"}
== [0 "test"] ; in an alternate universe...
```

The design choice was not to do this.  `call` *always* returns the simple exit code.  Instead, if you care about the `/output` of a call, you pass a parameter by reference...into which Rebol will write the console results.

It's very flexible, because Rebol lets you (for instance) pass in a parameter which is an open file to write the results...as opposed to making you store a function return that might be very large and then writing it out.  Whether `call` should be writing to a file or putting the results in a string is cued by the data type of the "by reference" parameter.

In short, this is a design decision of the language.  Rather than making an assumption about where the output should go, Rebol "sniffs" the parameter type and does the appropriate thing.  If you haven't established a data type for `content`...it can't work.  Again if we consider an "alternate universe", it would be *possible* for `call` to have different refinements:

```
call/outputstring {echo "test"} content
```

And then it wouldn't have to worry about whether `content` was previously declared, call would assume it's supposed to turn content into a string.  If you were writing to a file, it could create it for you...like this:

```
call/outputfile {echo "test"} %/myfile.txt content
```

But that wouldn't let you write into an arbitrary location of an already-existing file, or a position in an existing string.  Simply put, requiring `content` to be previously declared finesses this.  But as you've noticed, it takes a little more code.  You could, if you wished, put the declaration inline:

```
call/output {echo "test"} content: {}
```

Comment: I laughed because your answer always surprise me it's so thoughtfull and brilliant I got a headache each time, will have to re-read this week-end thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. If you do a HELP on CALL, you'll see that the /OUTPUT option requires an argument of one of following types: string!, port!, file!, url! or none!. When you just pass CONTENT word without defining it, you are passing an unset! value which doesn't match the argument expected type, hence generates an error.